# How do I install Macports and Xcode for OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, xcode, macports

I'm new to OS X and I have an older Snow Leopard system.  I need to compile a few simple C programs for some analysis work.  It seems that `gcc` et al are part of a package called Xcode, and that many free software programs are in a package called Macports.

It seems that Macports requires Xcode.  Xcode is not available for Snowleopard unless I have a $99/year developer subscription.  Alternatively I can install Lion for $30.

So to compile a tiny C program, I need to download some 5GB of upgrades and updates to upgrade to Lion, then download some 4GB iso to install Xcode?

Seriously?  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Did you check your installation DVD (in case you got one)? Xcode might actually be on it already.

Comment: XCode *is definitely* on the installation DVD--if you got one.

Comment: I think I might have gotten confused about needing 4.something.  My Google searches all brought up the story about how it doesn't exist on the website, but it didn't mention that 3.2 is on the DVD.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can register as a developer for free on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/). Scroll down to the bottom of the page for

[image]

Once registered you can download Xcode 3.2.6 from the developer site:

[image]