# Xcode update for 10.6.8

Tags: macos, development, xcode, gcc

I would like to use a newer version of Xcode (current version on my system is 3.2.4) and the command line tools (gcc & make).

I have tried to install Xcode through the Mac App Store, however I am prompted that my OS X version is too old. I then tried to download the respective tools and Xcode from developer.apple.com but all the provided packages are not suited for my system.

So my question basically boils down to

1. Is there a way to update Xcode so that I might use gcc & make?
2. If not, is there a free way to upgrade my OS so that I could use the Xcode that is provided on app store?

Comment: Which versions of gcc and make you need

Comment: Your version 3.2.4 already has gcc and make on board, why do you need a newer version of Xcode?

Comment: Are you sure gcc and make are already provided? starr:~ juser$ gcc
-bash: gcc: command not found

Answer (score 4):

Confirming couple of points

1. You are running OSX 10.6.8
2. Current Xcode version in your machine is 3.2.4

Xcode 4.2 should work fine on your machine. 
I have a snowleopard machine at office running Xcode 4.2, i updated it via the Mac App store only. Ok. If this is not working via Mac App store, then go to your developer account (free or paid) and then download the Xcode version for Snow Leopard and install it manually. Just make sure you are downloading the Snow Leopard edition not the Lion edition. Please don't hesitate to ask for assistance :-)

Edit : Here i am attaching a snapshot of where to find the link . You need to scroll down and check in the Downloads section.

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. The points you listed are correct. The problem is there is no version for snow leopard on the developer site.

Comment: I have just attached the image . Please check and let me know if you could find it.

Comment: @iGameram - what is the URL and do you have a paid Apple developer

Comment: XCode 4 for Snow Leopard seems to only be available for developers with a paid account. XCode versions up to 3.2.6 for SL, and the back catalogue of versions for Lion can be downloaded for free from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action though. Note that the last iOS SDK for Snow Leopard is 5.0; 5.1 is Lion+-only.

Comment: @Mark i have a paid account but as pmjordan said, it is available for the free account too. My account has actually expired so, it is right now in free developer state. I am not sure whether they allow the 'once-paid' developer account to download it even after expiry. Right now i can confirm that it is present in my account -> downloads section

Comment: It is not in mine - I only have a unpaid account

Comment: Hello! I still do not see the link for Snow Leopard. Also I've stumbled uppon this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3537806?start=0&tstart=0 discussing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides a free developer account which gives the newest Xcode for Snow Leopard as 4.3.6 from the [downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

See the answer to [How do I install Macports and Xcode for OS X Snow Leopard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/55233/9058) for detailled instructions.